# Why does my VS2008 debugging session always quit on me when stepping through ASP.NET MVC controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 RTM.  I'm using the ASP.NET MVC that you get from the Web Platform Installer.

When I step through my program and pause on any line for longer than a few seconds the debugger suddenly stops and the following message is printed in the Debug Output:

The program '[4232] WebDev.WebServer.EXE: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It does not happen 100% of the time, but it's often enough to be extremely frustrating.  This behavior happened in the W7 RC releases as well but never under Windows XP Pro x86.

Comment: Does it do this on all your MVC projects?

Comment: Are you using any WCF components that might be timing out?

Comment: @Matt Yes, all of them.  Using Unity as my IoC container in two of them, the others are just stock MVC.  Happens consistently on two different W7 installs.

Comment: @Terry Donaghe: No WCF in any of the projects.

Comment: New workstation, new install of W7 Ultimate, new install of VS2010, MVC 3, etc. and the problem is gone.  Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on, but if this were happening to me the first thing I would do is click on Debug-> Exceptions, and go make sure all the possible culprits are checked off under Managed Debug Assistants and Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

IIS has a ping timeout to the process that host your site. I think the default is 90 seconds.

While in IIS, right click on the application pool that is running your application and select "Advanced Settings...". Scroll down to "Ping Maximum Response Time" and change it to a greater value. On my development machine, I use 600 which is 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm using the ASP.NET Development Server included with VS, not IIS.  Does your comment still apply?

Comment: mmm I don't think it apply in this case.